# How to remove the big banner from Software Center?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

In the new version of Ubuntu Software Center there is a big banner under toolbar. It's useless for me. How do I remove it?

Comment: The best solution is to simply **not use** Ubuntu software center until the checkbox removing the advertisement is available. Another needed checkbox would be the one allowing the user to see or not the non-free soft (as in "free speech" but also as in "free beer"). Use ***Synaptic*** instead until the Software center karma improve a little!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This banner ad was bugging the hell out of me too.  I figured out how to remove it, but this might void your warranty or whatever so do this at your own risk:

1. Close Ubuntu Software Center and make a backup copy of
   `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py`
2. Edit that file as root:
   `sudo gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py`
3. Find the line which defines `MAX_HEIGHT = 200` (line 229 or so)
4. Change `MAX_HEIGHT` to 10
5. Save the file, restart software center, banner no longer obtrusive.

Comment: Typically, Ubuntu is provided with no warranty, so there's no need to worry about (literally) voiding it. If Ubuntu is provided by your OEM, then it's possible (but not guaranteed) that there is some software warranty through them.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py
```

find `self._append_banner_ads()` and comment it out with `#`.

```
#self._append_banner_ads()
```

Save file, restart Software Center. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVT0HZDqMq0 for more information

In Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04, the file is:
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py

Answer (score 0):

That area is reserved for "featured" apps and other promotions. It will change periodically now that Ubuntu 11.10 is released. It cannot be changed or removed.

Comment: I understand it. But I think many users want a checkbox that removes this annoying advertisement.

Comment: _"It cannot be changed or removed."_ Forgive my ignorance but I thought that a key element of Linux is that this sentence never applies.