# How to disable advertisement from ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the big banner from Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65770/how-to-remove-the-big-banner-from-software-center)

How can i disable the advertisements in the ubuntu software center?

thanks for your help.

Joe Hollik

Comment: Same as this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/65770/how-to-remove-the-big-banner-from-software-center

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, unless you want to rewrite the source code and compile it yourself. Of course, you can always install packages from the command line, using apt-get or aptitude. There's also synaptic.