# Remove or hide magazines from the Software Center

Tags: software-center

I just started using Ubuntu again (after using Max OSX for 2 years), and the one thing that bothers be about it are the magazines spamming the software center.

Is it possible to totally remove them from the listings?

Comment: Sounds like its similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/65770/how-to-remove-the-big-banner-from-software-center but you want to get rid of all the magazine suggestion instead. I dont think Software Center has that feature right now. But there is always other options in Ubuntu, for example you can try Synaptic.

Comment: Why do you use the term "spamming"?

Comment: Because there are many of them, and without a way to sort or manage them, They are very much spam. And besides, shouldn't there a separate program for media such as books, music, videos and magazines. They simply don't belong (regardless of subject).

Comment: @vasa1 because a "Software Center" should not contain magazines imo.

Comment: I saw both of the question you mention, @Aras and StephenMyall. Sadly they are not what I look for. Commercial apps are a different matter than magazines. And the big banner doesn't bother me since it usually contains an ad for a program and no magazine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the Magazines from searches I'm afraid.  And the reason why you will see them so often is they make use of he keyword search system that USC offers developers.  Magazines cover a lot of subjects.